# Java error: not a statement and I don't know why?

Tags: java

I'm really not sure what is causing this compile time error to occur???? I've been trying to figure it out and can't seem to find what the problem is.

```
ClassTable.java:253: error: not a statement
                class_c class = classes.nextElement();
                ^

ClassTable.java:253: error: ';' expected
                class_c class = classes.nextElement();
                       ^

ClassTable.java:253: error: <identifier> expected
                class_c class = classes.nextElement();
                             ^
ClassTable.java:253: error: <identifier> expected
                class_c class = classes.nextElement();
                                                   ^

ClassTable.java:254: error: illegal start of expression
                class_c parent = table.getClass(class.getParent());
                                                ^

ClassTable.java:254: error: ';' expected
                class_c parent = table.getClass(class.getParent());
                                                                 ^

ClassTable.java:264: error: illegal start of expression
        list.add(class);
                 ^

ClassTable.java:264: error: ';' expected
        list.add(class);
```

Here's my Code:

```
class ClassTable {
private int semantErrors;
private PrintStream errorStream;
private Hashtable<class_c,ArrayList<class_c>> table;
private boolean noCycles = true;

public void addClass(class_c c){
    Hashtable<class_c, ArrayList<class_c>> table = this.table();

    if(table.containsKey(c)){
        errorStream.print(c.getFilename() + ":" + c.getLineNumber() + ": " + "Class " + c.getName() + " was previously defined.");
        System.out.println();
        this.semantError();

    }
    else{
        ArrayList<class_c> list = new ArrayList<class_c>();
        table.put(c,list);
    }

}

public void addChildren(){
    Enumeration classes = this.table.keys();

    while(classes.hasMoreElements())
    {

        class_c class = classes.nextElement();
        class_c parent = table.getClass(class.getParent());


    if(!table.containsKey(parent)){
        errorStream.print(c.getFilename() + ":" + c.getLineNumber() + ": " + "Class "+ c.getName() + " inherits from an undefined class " + c.getParent()+".");
        System.out.println();
        this.semantError();
    }
    else{
    ArrayList<class_c> list = table.get(parent);
    list.add(class);
    this.table.put(parent,list);
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

HELP ME PLEASE. Why do I keep getting this error????

Comment: `class` is a reserved word in java. change your variable name

Comment: UGH what an idiot I am. Thanks so much for the help, that fixed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class` needs to be `clazz` or something else. `class` is a reserved name in Java.

Other Java keywords are:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use any of the keywords as identifiers in your programs. For you information, here  is a list of keywords: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved key word in java used to define java class.
For example:

```
class Test{
}
```

Which defines a Test class.
So you should not use it to define variable or reference.
read about list of reserved words in java : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords